# perl script need improving mysql search code

Tags: mysql, search, keyword

i am trying to create search function in my perl script by mysql

in mysql database some name is `name.file.new.txt` and some name is `name file new txt` 
when i search `name file` only show result `name file new txt` and not show `name.file.new.txt`

i am trying if i search `name file` result will show `name.file.new.txt` and `name file new txt`

my mysql perl function is

```
my $filter = "AND (file_name LIKE '%$f->{k}%' OR file_descr LIKE '%$f->{k}%')" if $f->{k}=~/^[^\"\'\;\\]{3,}$/;
```

Thank You

Comment: create a new table where you save separate tokens based on filename this way you can directly query and chain with AND (but sure to have a index on the tokens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regular expressions [MySQL reg exp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

1) form regular expression in perl `$f->{k} =~ s/[ .]/[ .]/g;`

2) use it in mysql query `AND (file_name regexp '.*$f->{k}.*' OR ...`

Comment: He wants an improvment not a suicidal Regular Expression that really mess up speed in MySQL or anny database..

Comment: i see no speed requirements in his question